# Why request() helper function returns null

Tags: laravel

According episode 19 Laravel 5.4. from Scratch (time 4:53) from laracasts.com video, code `request(['name', 'email', 'password'])` should return array containing name, email and password from user registration form.

But in my case it returns `null`.

I'm sure, form is ok because `request()->only(['name', 'email', 'password'])` works. It returns `Array( [name] => awesomename [email] => email@email.com [password] => asdfadsf)` properly.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the helper:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-request

It only gets the current request or obtains an input item. It does not accept an array as an argument.

```
$request = request();

$value = request('key', $default = null)
```

Comment: I know. And that's the reason why I don't understand video. Is it bug?

Comment: Nope, you're just using the helper incorrectly. That method signature only allows for one key being passed at a time.

Comment: Please watch  [https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/19?autoplay=true](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/19?autoplay=true), time 4:53

Comment: @Miloslav21 can you provide link to the video?

Comment: What am I watching for here? this is 22 minutes long.

Comment: 4:53. Yes he uses it like this `request([fields]);` and out of curiosity I tried dumping `return request(['title']);` in one of my projects. It returns title as it should. I'm not sure why you're having problems. It works as intended (and as in video) for me. The project I tried it in is also L5.4

Comment: @devk `request(['title']);` returns string, but in video is `request(['name', 'email', 'password'])` and this returns `null`.

Comment: @Miloslav21 [Here (gif)](http://imgur.com/a/C3oBT) is a gif. It works for me like it does in Laracasts.